# Is "redmere" technology in HDMI cables useful or is it marketing?

Tags: hdmi, cable

I'm in the market for some longer HDMI cables and came across HDMI cables with [Redmere technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RedMere) inside. The promise is that:

> It allows HDMI cables to be manufactured at lower cost with the same results as regular HDMI cables. By using a lot less copper, it allows for thinner and more flexible cables.

That sounds great to me. I'm looking to get several cables at 25 feet and 50 feet and will have to travel with them. Thinner, means lighter, means money and backbones saved.

However, cables seems a difficult industry with a lot of marketing ploys to get you to buy what you don't need. Is Redmere technology significantly better *in practice*? I've looked at a lot of HDMI cables on Amazon today and only one advertised Redmere, but almost none of them tell you the wire or cable thickness, so it's hard to compare. Worse, for my needs, weight is important, but they don't tell you that either.

---

Example product advertising Redmere HDMI:

> RedMere chip enables a clear signal over long distances and allows for a thinner, more pliable wire gauge for improved cable flexibility and portability
>   [Description on Amazon HDMI cable with Redmere](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01JH70GBY).

---

Side note:

If there's anything I *should* want in 25 and 50 lengths of HDMI, please let me know.

**Update:**

I *did* buy two 50 foot lengths of the Amazon listing linked above. They work great, but don't really seem much lighter or flexible than regular cables. Maybe a little, but not much. One issue is that they are not bi-directional. They have a "source" end and a "monitor" end. I didn't realize that until I tried to use one in the field and had it revered. I almost came back here to complain about a DOA. Considering the price and solid construction, I'll probably buy more and of different lengths too, but I don't notice the Redmere doing anything special. I'll update again with actual weight and circumference when I remember and get a chance.

If you do know anything about Redmere specs and actual quality/weight ratios or something, please do answer.

Comment: [I asked for opinions in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39140152#39140152), if anyone's interested.

Comment: In what context are you using the cables? The answer may differ if you are using the cables for set technology or for connecting a camera to a recorder, etc.

Comment: @MichaelLiebman Primarily, it will be to record a laptop send. I typically split off from a projector. In the future, I hope to also take in the output from a Sony cam, specifically, the HDR-FX7.

Answer (score 1):

I've used a 25ft HDMI with RedMere purchased from Amazon for about 3 years now.  Connecting a MacPro to a Yamaha ARx3070 Home theater amp. Predominantly for HiRes audio. I was skeptical as well. At the time of purchase, I wasn't able to find info online regarding RedMere. My understanding is the RedMere boosts the signal over the extended distance. Basically making it an "active" cable without requiring its own power source. With standard HDMI cables, I often experienced handshake issues upon power up between the computer and amp. Not an issue with this cable. I don't get how the cable being single direction still sends a signal in the opposite direction.  But clearly, my Mac receives a signal and is aware of the details from the amp. The funny thing is, since I installed this cable, I've not been able to get the two devices to connect with any other HDMI cable. Even with a HDMI cable that had previously worked.
I came across this thread researching RedMere again as I'm purchasing a new active HDMI 2.1 one direction fiber optic/ethernet cable with additional AC power connections on each end. I'm curious if it will work in place and how the ethernet functions in one direction. It had better.  At 20X the cost I'm also expecting it give a good old-fashioned handy before bed, if not a hummer. Fingers crossed...